# InstallShield X not able to add Single Value to Registry Entry

Tags: installshield

I am making a Windows Installer using InstallShield X.
I am not able to add single value to Registry.

Like in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order

ProviderOrder key Value is WDNP32,Mvfs,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,WebClient , now to this i want to append a comma seperated value like ,Test.
But i am not able to do that.
If I am making entry with whole value during uninstallation it removes windows entry and my system shows blue screen during restart.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't say what you've put in for the value, I'm assuming you've not already tried `[~],AppendThis`. That might work (per the Value column of the [Registry Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371168%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Although in general, I shy away from modifying anything under CurrentControlSet directly.